# SQL Server 2008 extremely slow using FTS on joined tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, full-text-search

I have two tables

```
Product (id int, brandid int,Name nvarchar(1000)) 2+ million rows 
Brand (id int,name nvarchar(1000)) 20k rows
```

FullText index is enabled on both table's name field.

If I do a search such as

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM   Product p join Brand b
         on p.BrandID = b.ID
WHERE  contains(b.name,'calvin')
```

Runs super fast (less than a second).  Same result if ran against p.name field.

But this query

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM   Product p join Brand b
         on p.BrandID = b.ID
WHERE  contains(b.name,'calvin')
       OR
       contains(p.Name,'calvin')
```

takes over a minute (several minutes actually).  If OR is changed to AND it is also super fast.

I cannot use unions or containstable since I'm using nhibernate.

Comment: Can you post the execution plans for AND and OR for the last query?

Comment: I saved the plans as sqlplan files.  Drop the .txt to open.
http://staging.entechsolutions.com/entech_site/uploads/contains_exec_plan_AND.sqlplan.txt
and
http://staging.entechsolutions.com/entech_site/uploads/contains_exec_plan_OR.sqlplan.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read up [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Queries on Large Catalogs: Lessons Learned](http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2007/11/21/sql-server-2005-full-text-queries-on-large-catalogs-lessons-learned.aspx).

Any query with OR is a possible source of performance problems. An OR between the two tables of a join, that is like an invitation for disaster since the optimizer has basically lost any information how to optimize the join. Throw in full text condition, which will make cardinaility prediction (number of rows that match the condition) a wild guess at best and you got yourself a perfect storm.

Get rid of the OR. Period. Modify your requirements, discard the middle man (ORM layers).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't know if we can modify requirements, but I guess we'll need to change the ORM access.

Thanks